# Estimating insertion depth of node in a d-heap

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, tree, heap

Is there any approach to estimating the insertion depth of a node in a d-heap that is able to beat `(node_value / heap_max) * h`, where h is the heap height, and heap_max is normalized to the heap minimum?

In this particular case, it is feasible to maintain extra/historical data to support this heuristic, given that the maintenance of which is O(1) in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to *Inserting a new element into a heap* [Doberkat, 1981] binary heaps with a uniform key distribution see an average of 1.6 UpHeap operations per insertion. The equivalent number should be fairly close for a d-heap.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly O(1), but a O(loglogn) (for all practical purposes O(1) ) solution would be to store some kind of level stat. Eg. You can store max of each level and do a binary search.

Comment: Does this actually improve on the naive heuristic, though?

Comment: empiricism to the resuce. let's see what we end up with in practice :)